# Youtube API v3 OAuth2 handshake error "connection failed" on Windows server

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-data-api, youtube-data-api, oauth-2.0

We want to use the Youtube v3 API in Combination with ASP.NET 4.5/C# to upload videos to a specific youtube channel via a Console Application. The compilation is done in a Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 7 Professional Development machine.

So we created OAuth2 credentials within the Google Developer Console and use the following code for the OAuth2 authorization handshake

```
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                DataStore = new FileDataStore(GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder)
            };

            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                initializer,

                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
                user,
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }
```

Everything works fine so far. If no authorization happened before, a browser windows opens (*access_type=offline&response_type=code*) where we can login to our Youtube account, select a channel, grant the necessary access rights, come back to a browser page *localhost:portnumber/authorize?code=XYZ* where it is written "**Received verification code. You may close this windows**", and our console application continues its work. This is the working workflow on our development machine.

However, when we copy the application to a Windows Server 2012, an error occurs. The browser window also opens and we can login and grant the access rights, but the final browser page *localhost:portnumber/authorize?code=XYZ* fails to load with a browser-specific "**connection failed**" error page.

It seems like no process is being attached to the (random?) port number to read the received code information, retrieve the tokens and to write it to %AppData%/Google.Apis.Auth. The firewall does not block anything.

Our first guess was a name resolution issue. By default, localhost was resolved to ::1 on the Windows server. Unfortunately it still does not work when we force an IPv4 resolution to 127.0.0.1

Thanks for every suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

We had bind the IIS8 to a specific IP address, not including 127.0.0.1.

After we added the local IP address via *netsh http add iplisten*, the webserver was able to bind to the localhost socket for the one-time code based authorization again.